# search similar words in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a db with a table called drugs. In that is a field called 'Description' that has a full text index . I want to search similar words '**Acifree -O 10ml**' ,'**Acifree O 10ml**' like that.

I tried with below query,

```
SELECT * FROM drugs where SOUNDEX(Description) = SOUNDEX('Acifree -O 10ml');
```

But the query returns following values

```
|ID  |Description          |
----------------------------
|177 |Acifree -O 10ml      |
|541 |Acifree O 10ml       |
|817 |Acifree -O 5ml       |
|817 |Acifree -O 7ml       |
|916 |Acifree -O 5 ml      |
```

I want only '**Acifree -O 10ml**' and '**Acifree O 10ml**' values. like following

```
|ID  |Description          |
----------------------------
|177 |Acifree -O 10ml      |
|541 |Acifree O 10ml       |
```

Is there any solution ?

Comment: Fix your data!  You should have things like the dosage in a separate column.

Comment: This data in in old DB. So I want to extract the data to my new DB with removing similar words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try  like below by using aggregate function

```
select *, MATCH(Description) AGAINST('Acifree -O 10ml' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
as score
from tutorial 
where MATCH(Description) AGAINST('Acifree -O 10ml' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
and MATCH(Description) AGAINST('Acifree -O 10ml' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)=
(select  max(MATCH(Description) AGAINST('Acifree -O 10ml' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE))
from tutorial
)
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c5b5a7a056dc0b16ce1ff776182ec49f)

output

```
id  description score
1   Acifree -O 10ml 0.15835624933242798
2   Acifree O 10ml  0.15835624933242798
```

When `MATCH()` is used in a WHERE clause, the rows returned are automatically sorted with the highest relevance first.
Relevance values are non negative floating-point numbers.
Zero relevance means no similarity.
Relevance is computed based on -

- the number of words in the row
- the number of unique words in that row
- the total number of words in the collection
- the number of documents
  (rows) that contain a particular word

As you need the best relevant so i took the max score

Comment: Thanks. This is the query exactly I want.